# dat-gui with Angular 4/TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get dat-gui to run in my Angular 4 app.

I've installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dat-gui,

```
import * as DatGui from "@types/dat-gui";
var gui = new DatGui.GUI()
```

..but get - error: Cannot find module "@types/dat-gui"

I'm presuming I'm missing the core library still but not sure what to do next?

Comment: That's only type definition for TypeScript. You need the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/dat-gui

Comment: But I think it's dat.GUI now: https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui

Comment: I have the similar problem. Any examples to make dat.gui to run in Angular Js 4?

Answer (score 3):

It works after following steps(angular 4.4.6)

```
npm install --save @types/dat-gui
npm install --save dat.gui
```

---

```
import {GUI} from "dat-gui";
...
ngOnInit() {
   const dat = require('dat.gui');
   const gui: GUI = new dat.default.GUI({width: 300}); //why default?
   let obj = {
      message: 'Hello World',
      displayOutline: false,
      maxSize: 6.0,
      speed: 5
    };

    gui.remember(obj);
    gui.add(obj, 'message');
    gui.add(obj, 'displayOutline');
...
}
```

Comment: The proper punctuation is `"dat.gui"` with a `.` period, not with a `-` dash. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dat.gui

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install --save @types/dat-gui
npm install --save dat.gui
```

---

```
import {GUI} from 'dat.gui';
```

---

```
gui!: GUI;
```

---

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.gui = new GUI();
   this.gui.addFolder('Folder 1');
}
```